# Backslashes before php variables

Tags: php, netbeans, backslash, emmet

When I try to add emmet comments in html codes that contain php code, slashes (`\`) are added before php vars.

For example I have this line:

```
<td class="item"><?php echo $var; ?></td>
```

If I try to comment it, it returns

```
<!-- <td class="item"><?php echo \$var; ?></td> -->
```

The `\` before `$var` should not be generated. The same thing happens if I try to remove tags. Am I missing something here?

Comment: May be you should try something like this <!-- <td class="item">--><?php echo $var; ?><!-- </td>-->

Comment: If you are commenting using html tags then the php code which is inside that html comment will execute, to avoid this emment is using this kind of slash.

Comment: Are you using the comment button in netbeans to add this? if so this does not happen in version 7.4 (on my machine at least)